# MVP: Can a view controller message a presenter of another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, mvp

THere are 2 view controllers: master and detail view. They both have a presenter as I'm implementing the MVP pattern.

I need to update the data in the detail view controller.

I'm using this code in the master view controller.

```
detailVC.presenter?.set(data: presenter?.data[row])
```

I'm getting the data from the presenter of the master view controller and passing it to the presenter of the detailVC.

Is this good design?

Answer (score 1):

If you create DetailVC before, you can use like that. Also u can use delegate patterns for that. MasterVC must have a delegate for DetailVC. Whenever you need to set your data you can use delegate.set(data: presenter?.data[row]) in your MasterVC class. But don't forget to set MasterVC delegate.

But if u want to create DetailVC and set parameters, u can use init method. Create an init function for your detailVC with the required parameters like that.. Write that function into your DetailVC class or create a DetailViewControllerInit class for your custom init functions with different parameters..

```
static func initDetailVC(data: DataType?) -> UIViewController { 
  let vc = UIStoryboard.... // create DetailVC here..
  let presenter = viewController.presenter
  presenter.set(data) // or presenter.data = data
  return vc
}
```

After that u can create DetailVC in MasterVC like that

`let detailVC = DetailVC.initDetailVC(data: presenter.data[row])`

Comment: Yeah, that would be the other alternative. But I was wondering, if I pass the data to the view controller, than the view controller needs to pass them to the presenter anyway, and if I change the data model, I need to update view controller code too.

Comment: Actually, you can pass data directly to DetailVC presenter. You don't need to set delegate for DetailVC. You can change that delegate for DetailPresenter. After that if you change your data model, you just need to update DetailPresenter. 
Also if you use detail presenter delegate, you can see all the functions and parameters that need to be set different places.. I think, with this approach, it becomes more tidy. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Though your implementation would certainly work, here are a couple of things to consider in order to improve it:

1) It hinges upon the master view controller knowing about a lot of different things (the detail view controller, the presenter, and the presenter's API). This can create coupling, which can make it more difficult to later refactor your code. Instead of calling `detailVC.presenter?.someMethod()`, I would consider adding a pass through method to detailVC that handles the calling of the presenter method (as well as anything else it needs to do at the same time) so that your architecture will be more modular and it will be easier to later swap out components.

2) I would consider decoupling the view and the model. Since MVP is really M<->P<->V in practice, ideally your model and view would not really communicate with or know about each other. Here, it seems like the view, or at least the object in which this line of code lives, knows about model when you call `detailVC.presenter?.set(data: presenter?.data[row])`. In order to do this decoupling, you could just have the view send an event / message prompting the presenter to do its thing, rather than manipulate the data directly. For example: `detailVC.presenter?.newInputReceived(input: "hey!")`

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would like to discuss further both your points. (1) It's true that with the current implementation the master view controller needs to know about the detail's presenter. However if I pass the data to the detail view controller (which is successively passing it to its presenter), I need to update the view controller protocol (i'm using protocol for all entities) to accept that specific data model. Instead right now the view controller protocol knows nothing about the data model. What's your comment about that?

Comment: (2) I don't fully understand this remark. Indeed the model is another object and it's not part of the presenter. But the presenter owns the model, so it correctly has a property called data, which is a reference to the model. The presenter takes care of data transformation and representation, but it doesn't contain the data in my design.

Comment: Sure thing. For the first part, I was really just saying that calling `detailVC.presenter?.doSomething()` requires that master view controller knows the inner workings of the presenter. Instead, you could change this method call (and likely your protocols as well) to something like `detailVC.doSomething()`. That detailVC method could then call the presenter's `doSomething()` method. It adds a layer of friction, yes, but it also decouples the masterVC from the presenter. That way, if the presenter changes down the road, you only have to update your detailVC code, not both detailVC and masterVC.

Comment: For the second part, I was just saying that it seems weird for the view to say, "Hey presenter, set your data to this, which is a subset of the model you own." I would recommend the following instead: simply pass a command from the view to the presenter telling it that it should update its data. Since MVP is really MPV in practice, I don't think the view should know about or manipulate the model directly. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Let me know if you have further ?s.

Comment: All right, yes, I got your points. My only issue is that, indeed, since my data is a bit more complex than a string "hey!", I need to pass a struct (which is defined in the model) to the detail view controller first, which is then passed to its presenter (following the flow in your point 1). So that the view needs to know about the model, in order to pass it to its presenter. This is my only doubt now.

Comment: Otherwise I should create a new struct similar to the one in the model, just to store the data to pass between view controllers, and that is ultimately passed to  the presenter's newInputReceived method.

Comment: I actually just realized I was reading your original code incorrectly. I now see that when you say `detailVC.presenter?.set(data: presenter?.data[row])`, the second reference to `presenter` actually refers to the masterVC's presenter, not the detail's. That makes me think that what you have is actually pretty good and that you can essentially disregard my second point. If you want to tighten things up, however, you could still add those pass-through methods to decouple the views and the models. For example, `presenter?.getData(atIndex:)` instead of `presenter?.data[row]`. Not required though.

Comment: Ok. Regarding the design: I'm not sure what is best. If I let a presenter call other presenter method, as you said, I give up on decoupling each MVP. However, if I communicate through view controllers, I need to pass them the data model, (which is successively passed to the respective presenter), and I'm giving up on decoupling view and model: the view doesn't own the model, but if I change the model, I need to change the view protocol as well, because it's used in view method parameters.

Comment: Yeah, these decisions are rarely black and white, especially given different use cases. If you want to send me more info on your specific use case via chat, I'm happy to try to answer some of the things you posed in this most recent comment.